# Cordova media plugin Not working in ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova media plugin in my Kendo mobile application. It is working the only for android, but when i tried in ios its not working.

My code:

```
 Media.js file inside the www root floder of plugin 

 cordova.define("cordova/plugin/ExternalMedia", function (require, exports, 
 module) {
     Media.prototype.start= function () {}
     Media.prototype.stop= function () {}
     Media.prototype.play = function () {}
     Media.prototype.pause= function () {}

 this is code inside plugin file media.js file in wwww root folder

  });

   <script>
       var externalmedia;
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
       function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("ios")
         //here i am calling the plugin,Its display all the methods inside 
    the cordova/plugin/ExternalMedia file for android, but for ios its not 
  working 
        externalmedia = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/ExternalMedia");
        alert(externalmedia);
    }
   </script>
```